# Repeater within repeater in apex and Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, list, map

Object :- MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c

Field 1 :- MBT_SFFB__Message__c

Field 2 :- MBT_SFFB__Author_URL__c

Field 3 :- MBT_SFFB__parent__c - **Lookup** with same object MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c

Field 4 :- MBT_SFFB__Is_Comment__c - If comment then it will contain **MBT_SFFB__parent__c**  lookup and checked the checkbox.

Wanna show as below.

Post 1 Hey this is the Pleasent Morning !

Post 2 Hey this is the dark night.

```
Comment 1 for post2 :- really dark.
```

Post 3 hey this is.

```
Comment 1 for post3 :- this is ??
Comment 2 for post3 :- Is this ??
```

**Repeater in repeater is the Idea . How to populate IT ?**

**Populated Post and List of comments in a map.**

tried this :- 
Binding done sucessfully with the map.

**But How to pupulate the Inner List ? of the Map ?**

Apex :-

```
public Map<MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c,list<MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c>> objmappostandcomment
```

Visual Force

```
<apex:repeat id="postrepeat" value="{!objmappostandcomment}" var="post">                            
  <p class="fb-user-status">
   {!post.MBT_SFFB__Message__c}
  </p>                             
  <ul class="fb-comments">
    <apex:repeat id="commentrepeat" value="{!post}" var="comment">                                   
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="cmt-thumb">
              <img src="{!pagepicture}" alt="" />
          </a>
          <div class="cmt-details">
              <a href="{!comment.MBT_SFFB__Author_URL__c}">{!comment.MBT_SFFB__Message__c}</a>                                              
          </div>
      </li>
      </apex:repeat>
  </ul>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.It is possible to have repeat inside repeat.This is the example that I created:

controller

```
public class RepeaterInsideRepeater {
    public List<List<String>> getMainRepeat(){

        List<String> subRepeat1 = new List<String>{'Post 1.1','Post 1.2','Post 1.3'};

         List<String> subRepeat2 = new List<String>{'Post 2.1','Post 2.2','Post 2.3'};

        List<List<String>> mainRepeat = new List<List<String>>{subRepeat1,subRepeat2};

        return mainRepeat;

    }

}
```

visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="RepeaterInsideRepeater">
    <apex:repeat value="{!mainRepeat}" var="main">
         <ul>Comment :
             <apex:repeat value="{!main}" var="x">
                <apex:outputText value="{!x}"/>
             </apex:repeat>

        </ul>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

feel free to enhance the code to suit your logic.

Comment: Your code Helped me Thank you !! 
Please check the updated code in question.. And please suggest How can i access innerlist  of map in visualforce ??